# Is OpenSSL enabled by default in PHP and since which version

Tags: php, ubuntu, wamp, lamp, php-openssl

I am not sure if the question is correct to be posted here but I am not able to find any reliable information.

I am building some PHP application which will run on a bunch of different servers, hosted by someone else. The application depends on `openssl` in PHP.

What I am trying to find out is `openssl` enabled by default in PHP and since which version, or it's always necessary to install it separately.

Somwhere I found that it's build into Ubuntu's PHP, and that you don't have, in Ubuntu, to enable it separately. Does anyone know if that's true and since which version. And what about other systems, or other ways of installing PHP.

This information is really necessary for me in order to design the application and would be really helpful if anyone have some information

Comment: Why is this necessary for you to design the application? The entire application design is based around if openssl is installed by default or not?

Answer (score 2):

Per http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php:

> To use PHP's OpenSSL support you must also compile PHP `--with-openssl[=DIR]`.

Ubuntu includes this flag by default. Rather than trying to figure out whether or not you can count on it being present, use `extension_loaded('openssl')` to check for its presence in your app and fail gracefully with some instructions if it's missing.